# How to ensure that Mac in network always remains connected to local Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, sharing, file-sharing

I have a Mac on my LAN which we use it as server.

From other Macs, we have to always connect it via  Go -> Connect To Server.
Is there a way by which I can have my Mac server always visible rather than connecting it manually via Go > Connect to Server?

Please let me know.

Comment: What services do you use on the Mac server?  Eg screen sharing, file sharing?

Comment: Server is for file sharing only.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can drag the items to your desktop to create Alias' that when you click will prompt for usernames and passwords.

Users can choose to remember the password in their keychain and they won't be asked for it again.

I use this solution for my server at home, dragged all the Alias' into a folder, put that folder in my Home Directory and then dragged it to the right side of the dock, I not have a nice stack full of the server shares I use regularly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the server as a login item.

Some documentation is available from [Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4011).

Does that cover your need to have it "always connected" or are you finding that it becomes disconnected separate from logging in and out on the client side?